# Different user types in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am creating a web application but I am not very comfortable with database designs.
So user can only be an enterprise or an organisation, so I added a picture here with my idea. 
But is there a better way to deal with that kind of user types? 
Or there should be just two seperate tables (enterprise, organisation) with login credentials and etc.

[image: an example]

Comment: You can have 1 table & add new column as usertype.

Comment: It's up to you. Both solutions are well known. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757055/database-design-question-discriminatory-column-vs-foreign-key/757069

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would class an Org and a Enterprise as the same thing (Database wise) as you can see by looking at your columns. They are all the same except for `register number` but I'm sure Organisations also have a unique ID number.

If I was doing this I would have:

```
User m->1 Business m->1 BusinessType
```

Also should a User not belong to a Company/enterprise/organisation? The way you have it only one user can ever be associated with each. If you had the FK on the User side you could associate many users with one organisation.